# How to configure endpoint in .csdef and .cscfg file?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-cloud-services

I need deploy an Azure service. Inside the .csdef file, I need define an input endpoint which I did (following here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-enable-communication-role-instances):

```
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="StandardWeb" protocol="http" port="80" localPort="80" />
</Endpoints>
```

The problem is I need deploy this package to 5 different web service and the "InputEndpoint"s are different for the 5 web service.

My question is do I need have 5 .csdef for the deployment? Is there any way to make use of the .cscfg ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Endpoints are specified in Cloud Service **Definition** files and not Cloud Service **Configuration** files because endpoints must be identical for all instances participating in a cloud service.

> I need deploy this package to 5 different web service

You will need to modify your Cloud Service for each different Cloud Service. Is there a reason they must be different?

Comment: Different service corresponds to different reversed IP.  So I need create 5 different packages just for "InputEndpoint"?

Comment: @derek I don't undestand what that has to do with endpoints. `.csdef` Cloud Service endpoints are not concerned with IP addresses at all, only port numbers.

Comment: that is a long story: I got an error when trying to turn off "remote desktop" on my Azure cloud service:  Validation Errors: Error validating the .cscfg file against the .csdef file. Severity:Error, message:ReservedIP 'NAME001' was not mapped to an endpoint. The service definition must contain atleast one endpoint that maps to the ReservedIP..